# Doing similar match in drools and not exact by checking levenshtein distance

Tags: drools

My use case is that while matching below in drools

```
Person(name=="A.P.J abdul kalam")
```

**This match should work for all the following data**

```
 1. A.P.J Abdul Kalam
 2. A.P.J. Abdul Kalam
 3. APJ Abdul Kalam
```

Can anything like this be done in drools??

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can express your requirement as a regex, it can be done by using the [matches](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_the_operator_matches) operator.

The rule should look similar to this:

```
rule 'Match APJ Abdul Kalam' 
  Person(name matches "A(\\.)?P(\\.)?J(\\.)? Abdul Kalam")
then
  //...
end
```

---

If your problem can't be solved using a regex, then what you can do is to use an implementation of the Levenshtein Distance algorithm in a utility class and then do something like this:

```
rule 'Match name' 
  Person(Utils.levenshtein(name, "APJ Abdul Kalam"))
then
  //...
end
```

Hope it helps,